# CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology changed in iOS 14 crash

Tags: ios14

```
if (@available(iOS 12.0, *)) {
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo * tmp = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    if ([tmp respondsToSelector:@selector(serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology)]) {
        [tmp.serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull key, NSString * _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            currentRadioAccessTechnology = obj;
            *stop = YES;
        }];
    }
    tmp = nil;
}
```

**before iOS14 currentRadioAccessTechnology is NSString** and
**iOS14 currentRadioAccessTechnology is NSArray**

```
if (currentRadioAccessTechnology)
    {
        if ([currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE])
        {
            returnValue =  network_4g;
        }
        else if ([currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge]
                 || [currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS])
        {
            returnValue =  network_2g;
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue =  network_3g;
        }
        return returnValue;
        
    }
```

**if ([currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE])** crashed  error info [__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance